# Hide a Pandas Column while using style.apply

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-styles

I am using df.style.applymap to render a pandas dataframe. I chose style instead of to_html as I needed css applied based on some of the column values. The challenge is that I want to exclude one of those columns from display. So, with the following code:

```
html = df.style.applymap(color_cell, subset=['columnName']).render()
with open('output.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(html)
```

Is there way I can exclude/hide a column that I require for styling other columns?

Comment: why not simply: `df.drop(['col1','col2'], axis=1).style.applymap(color_cell, subset=['columnName']).render()` ?

Comment: Ty Max! That was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can drop columns that you want to hide when rendering HTML:

```
cols_2_hide = ['col1','col2']
df.drop(cols_2_hide, axis=1).style.applymap(color_cell, subset=['columnName']).render()
```

Answer (score 9):

From `pandas v1.4.0` use [`.hide`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.hide.html) with `axis='columns'`. [`.hide_columns`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.5/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.hide_columns.html) is deprecated.

---

If you need the columns that are being hidden in the function color_cell you can use hide_columns feature of styler.

```
df.style.hide_columns([hide_cols_list]).applymap(color_cell, subset=['columnname' + hide_cols_list]).render()
```